# Opinions of different sampradayas regarding shudras and women chanting pranava?

Tags: women, shudra, om, pranava

I have heard from a few madhwas that shudras and women are allowed to chant pranava and that srivaishnavas allow pranava in ashtakshari

Comment: Only among Teṉkalais (not among Vaṭakalais) is praṇavajapa allowed alongwith aṣṭākṣarī (praṇava japa with other mantras or independently is still not allowed), for those who have done pañcasaṁskāra.

Comment: What is the madhwa stance? @Bingming

Comment: I am not sure about their stance on praṇava japa with aṣṭākṣarī. But they too don't agree with praṇava japa by non-dvijas generally. This is basically the dharmaśāstrika stance, so most proper sampradāyas agree upon it.

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you answer this question? https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/do-srivaishnavasthenkalai-vadakalai-consider-hanuman-an-avatar-of-shiva-or-any @Bingming

Comment: "most proper sampradāyas..."so are there any which disagree?