# Do srivaishnavas(thenkalai/vadakalai) consider hanuman an avatar of shiva or any other deva?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, hanuman, madhwa, srisampradaya, ramanandasampradaya

I'm aware that ramanandis regard hanuman as an avatar of shiva and madhwas consider him an avatar of vayu
What about srivaishnavas?